# Conditional include Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<div ng-include src="{{ headerLocation }}"></div>
```

And I have the following code in my controller:

```
var ER = angular.module('evidenceReviewerApp');

ER.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, appData, $location, $cookies) {

    // Some code

    if ( !! $cookies.loggedin || $cookies.loggedin == 'true' )
        $scope.headerLocation = 'login-header.html';
    else
        $scope.headerLocation = 'anon-header.html';

});
```

Of course I get the error `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'headerLocation' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 4 of the expression [{{ headerLocation }}] starting at [headerLocation }}].`

What I want to do is show a different partial depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div ng-include="headerLocation"></div>
```

that's all.

Comment: Oops. Still getting used to Angular as you probably can tell ;) Thanks for the answer.